# Is there ANY way to get a Smart Phone number from website?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I'm searching for a way to get the phone number of a device using HTML 5, Javascript or something like it. Recently, I wanted to get the coordinates of the device. I could easily do that by writing some JS like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I'm almost done with my part of the job, but the last thing I need to do is to get the phone number of the smartphone that access that website.

Is there ANY way to do this? :/ please... and thank you.

Comment: Almost definitely not. Anyway, if you do, you'll probably be violating some privacy laws for taking information like a phone number without user permission or knowledge.

Comment: `Is there ANY way to do this?` Yes; prompt the user to input their number.

Comment: from a JS perspective, data and voice flow though different pipes that's aren't connected or even aware of eachother.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the device's phone number through JavaScript in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003339/how-can-i-get-the-devices-phone-number-through-javascript-in-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reliable way to get a phone number with JavaScript without prompting the user. That is, it cannot be retrieved automatically using a browser API.

It is possible inside of certain Android / iPhone application views. See discussions here: [How can I get the device's phone number through JavaScript in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003339/how-can-i-get-the-devices-phone-number-through-javascript-in-android). And here: [Getting the local iPhone number through SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591430/getting-the-local-iphone-number-through-sdk)

As mentioned in comments, this is not a good thing to do in general (privacy, etc.). Definitely prompt the user for input if the phone number is needed.

Comment: "That is, it cannot be retrieved automatically using a browser API." There's any official documentation that states that behavior?

Comment: @PauloR.F.Amorim there is no documentation stating all the things that are not possible. Lack of documentation for a thing strongly hints at that not being possible / supported. My browser also cannot automatically brew me a coffee but where is the documentation saying that browser cannot brew coffee or make me sandwich?